# how to get rid of c3p0 deadlock error

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0, database-deadlocks

I'm using hibernate 4.3.6 with c3p0 0.9.2.1 and I'm getting the following error very frequently:

```
ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner:778 - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@9abc33e -- Running DeadlockDetector[Exiting. No pending tasks.]
```

This slows down the server and I have no idea what's causing it and how to get rig of it.

This is my hibernate.config file:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://ip:port/app?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">2</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
     <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
     <mapping class="server.c1"/>          
     <mapping class="server.c2"/>
     <mapping class="server.c3"/>
     <mapping class="server.c4"/>
     <mapping class="server.c5"/>
   </session-factory> 
</hibernate-configuration>
```

In addition I also have a c3p0.properties file:

```
c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout=true
c3p0.privilegeSpawnedThreads=true
c3p0.contextClassLoaderSource=library
```

There are a lot of questions about it but I couldn't find a concrete solution.

Comment: Have you tried changing `maxAdministrativeTaskTime` and `numHelperThreads` options as mentioned in the c3p0 document on this issue? Reference can be found at http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#maxAdministrativeTaskTime

Comment: Which values should I set?

Comment: Start with `numHelperThreads=10`. If problem persist add `maxAdministrativeTaskTime=3` (increase to a value that is long enough for the longest query to finish).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem with c3p0. My final solution was use this connection pool  https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP

Comment: This didn't solve my entire problem bug it certainly helped, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

<s>If you are still using c3p0, the following steps are likely to resolve this issue:</s>

1. Update to the latest c3p0 (now 0.9.5.2).
2. Set the following config parameter:

   `c3p0.statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads=1`

See the [docs](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads).

**Update:** Oh, wait. I responded too quickly. Sorry!

You are not actually seeing deadlocks, you are just seeing messages that the deadlock detector is running. The message that you are seeing is not an error at all, just a notification that gets logged at `TRACE` / `DEBUG` / `FINEST` (depending which logging library you use).

You should configure your logging so that loggers prefixed `com.mchange` log at `INFO`. That's it.